# on hover, add a div over the top of another

Tags: jquery, css, hover, addclass

I have some thumbnails, and when you hover over them, they will animate (using jQuery) and where i am stuck is to apply a div inside/over the current div being hovered which will have a background colour (opacity will be on it so you can see a little of the div underneath),and text in the div that will be shown.

I have been able to add a Class using jQuery with a border around the thumbnails but a background colour and text applied to the class it doesnt seem to like, can someone suggest where i am going wrong?

Here is an example of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hTB3q/

```
$('.video-thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-15px'
    }, 500);
    $(this).show('video-overlay');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

You needed some additional CSS on the `.video-overlay` and changing the selector for the `.video-overlay`
CSS

```
 .video-overlay {
     display:none;
     background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
     /* Fall-back for browsers that don't
                                    support rgba */
     background: rgba(58, 58, 58, .5);
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     float:left;
 }
```

Javascript

```
$('.video-thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-15px'
    }, 500);
    $('.video-overlay', this).show();
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 500);
    $('.video-overlay', this).hide();
});
```

JS fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/CkpZw/

Answer (score 1):

You could try the CSS approach: http://jsfiddle.net/xQdsN/2/

```
 .video-thumbnail {
     position:relative;
     margin:0 auto;
     width:20% !important;
     display:inline-block;
     border:1px solid red;
     height:100px;
 }
 .video-thumbnail img{
     max-height: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
     position: relative;
 }
.video-thumbnail:hover>.video-overlay{
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
 .video-overlay {
     position: absolute;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     top: 0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     bottom: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

No jQuery needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.video-thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $(this).finish().animate({
        top: '-15px'
    }, 500);
    $(this).find('.video-overlay').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).finish().animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 500);
    $(this).find('.video-overlay').hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xDS6a/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.video-thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-15px'
    }, 500);

    $('.video-overlay', this).stop().fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, 500);
   $('.video-overlay', this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UYM4N/